# Zero-initialize data using value-initialized array

Tags: c++, c++11

Will the following code correctly zero-initialize the memory returned from `malloc`?

```c++
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>

int main()
{
    char* p = new (std::malloc(10)) char[10]{};
}
```

Comment: You're probably doing something too smart for me to understand, but seeing a `malloc` and a `new` on the same line is making my eyes bleed so I gotta stop looking at it instead of figuring out what's going on here.

Comment: Why would you do that? How do you propose to free the memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it will zero-initialize memory because of the `{}` at the end of the line, as long as `malloc` doesn't fail from within the placement `new`.   Here's an alternative version that more completely proves the point.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <new>

char mongo[10];

int main()
{
    for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
        mongo[i] = 'a';
    char *p = new (mongo) char[10]{};
    for (int i= 0; i < 10; ++i)
        assert(p[i] == '\0');
}
```

This program will run and print nothing because the `mongo` array (aliased by `p`) is explicitly cleared by the initialization of `p`.  By contrast, if we omit the `{}` at the end of that line, the program will assert and terminate.

Note that in your version using `malloc`, you will have to explicitly destroy the object -- that's part of the responsibility that comes with placement `new` and among the few times in modern C++ where one must explictly call a destructor.

If, as in your particular case, you are allocating memory with `malloc()` you must issue a corresponding `free(p)` or your program will leak memory.

### The elephant in the room

(Thanks, @TC, for pointing to the big gray thing!)  Here's an explanation and example straight from the standard (section 5.3.4):

> Example:
>
> `new T` results in a call of `operator new(sizeof(T))`,
>
> `new(2,f) T` results in a call of `operator new(sizeof(T),2,f)`,
>
> `new T[5]` results in a call of `operator new[](sizeof(T)*5+x)`, and
>
> `new(2,f) T[5]` results in a call of `operator new[](sizeof(T)*5+y,2,f)`.
>
> Here, x and y are non-negative unspecified values representing array allocation overhead; the result of the *new-expression* will be offset by this amount from the value returned by `operator new[]`. This overhead may be applied in all array *new-expressions*, including those referencing the library function operator `new[](std::size_t, void*)` and other placement allocation functions. The amount of overhead may vary from one invocation of new to another.

In other words, if you use placement `new` for a single object, everything is fine and there is no inserted overhead, but if you allocate an **array** via placement `new`, there may be overhead, and it might not even be the same size from invocation to invocation.

Comment: How would I delete the memory in this case?

Comment: @templateboy: I've edited my answer to include the answer to that.

Comment: This is missing the elephant in the room. The unspecified array allocation overhead makes this code a terrible idea.

Comment: @T.C.: Thanks very much for pointing that out!  I rarely use placement `new` to allocate an array of objects and completely forgot about the possibility of array-handling overhead.

Answer (score 5):

This is a very, very bad idea.

Currently, placement array `new`, like all array `new` expressions, is allowed to add an unspecified amount of overhead. There is no portable way for the program to know how many bytes this overhead is.

Therefore, unless the implementation's array allocation overhead for `char[10]` is zero, your code has undefined behavior.

*If* the pointer points to sufficient memory to accommodate all the array elements plus the unspecified overhead amount (and that's a very big if, since there's no portable way for you to be sure), then the expression will indeed zero-initialize the memory.

Comment: So how would one initialize the data returned from `malloc` that's meant to allocate raw bytes? Must I loop and *placement-new* via `new (&buf[i]) char{}`?

Comment: @templateboy there's `std::uninitialized_copy/copy_n/fill/fill_n`.